# JMeter: How to get assured that requests hits from JMeter has reached at server if there is no way to verify on DB or any analytic tool

Tags: google-analytics, server, jmeter, response, hit

I see no way to verify specific requests been reached at Server end after hitting VUsers from JMeter.

Consider "About Us" is the page where 10000 VUsers hits at once from JMeter and Server shows some activity at Perfmon. No, Lets says, in JMeter, VUsers have reached 10000/10000 to 0/10000 but there is no way to keep track of how many users hit as Analytic is not implemented in App.

I want to make sure all 10000 VUSers have hit at once. Is there any way I can find out how many VUsers have visited "About Us" page from 10000 if JMeter doesnot show any failed response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can monitor request rate with custom listeners available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project like:

   - [Server Hits per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/)
   - [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/)
2. You can set desired request rate via [JMeter Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers), i.e.

   - [Constant Throughout Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)
   - [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

Answer (score 0):

To ensure you're really hitting your server, the best way is to check access logs of Web servers.

To then have some numbers in your report, use the new Web Report provided by JMeter 3.0:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

If you want live number:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html